# Facing issues while running the docker image created by jlink

Tags: spring-boot, docker

The application was running properly in eclipse and also as a jar file.
Once the docker image is created using jlink the spring boot application started without issue, but while using it getting the below exception.

```
2023-11-14 05:48:45.584   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet].log(175)               : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderInitializationException: Failed to lazily resolve the supplied JwtDecoder instance
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.SupplierJwtDecoder.wrapException(SupplierJwtDecoder.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.SupplierJwtDecoder.lambda$new$0(SupplierJwtDecoder.java:39)
        at org.springframework.util.function.SingletonSupplier.get(SingletonSupplier.java:97)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.SupplierJwtDecoder.decode(SupplierJwtDecoder.java:49)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:99)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:88)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)


2023-11-14 05:48:45.684   [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet].log(175)               : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderInitializationException: Failed to lazily resolve the supplied JwtDecoder instance
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.SupplierJwtDecoder.wrapException(SupplierJwtDecoder.java:53)
```

Below is the dockerfile which is used to build the image of the spring boot application

```
FROM amazoncorretto:21-alpine3.17-jdk as builder

ARG ARTIFACTORY_USER
ARG ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN ./gradlew build -Partifactory.password=${ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN} -Partifactory.username=${ARTIFACTORY_USER}
RUN ./gradlew copyDependencies 

RUN jdeps --ignore-missing-deps -q \
    --multi-release 21 --print-module-deps \
    --class-path="build/lib/*" \
    --module-path="build/lib/*" build/libs/user-network-dev-04.10.2023.01-plain.jar > jre-deps.info

RUN jlink --verbose \
    --compress 2 \
    --strip-java-debug-attributes \
    --no-header-files \
    --no-man-pages \
    --output jre \
    --add-modules $(cat jre-deps.info)

FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /application

COPY --from=builder /app/jre /jre

COPY --from=builder /app/build/lib/* lib/

COPY --from=builder /app/build/libs/user-network-dev-04.10.2023.01-plain.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["/jre/bin/java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with this issue for a day and found the reason that jdeps not generating the required modules properly

so one module,jdk.crypto.ec, which was missing added manually to dockerfile and this issue was resolved and working properly.

```
FROM amazoncorretto:21-alpine3.17-jdk as builder

ARG ARTIFACTORY_USER
ARG ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN ./gradlew build -Partifactory.password=${ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN} -Partifactory.username=${ARTIFACTORY_USER}
RUN ./gradlew copyDependencies 

RUN jdeps --ignore-missing-deps -q \
    --multi-release 21 --print-module-deps \
    --class-path="build/lib/*" \
    --module-path="build/lib/*" build/libs/user-network-dev-04.10.2023.01-plain.jar > jre-deps.info

RUN jlink --verbose \
    --compress 2 \
    --strip-java-debug-attributes \
    --no-header-files \
    --no-man-pages \
    --output jre \
    --add-modules jdk.crypto.ec,$(cat jre-deps.info)

FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /application

COPY --from=builder /app/jre /jre

COPY --from=builder /app/build/lib/* lib/

COPY --from=builder /app/build/libs/user-network-dev-04.10.2023.01-plain.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["/jre/bin/java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```